# fastest/performance approach to share large Bitmap object between managed and unmanaged functions

Tags: .net, performance, image-processing, c++-cli, computer-vision

While working on a computer vision application having GUI in WPF.NET and which is being processed using a native libraries (OpenCV and more),
What is the fastest way to send and receive large size Bitmaps between managed (C#.NET) and un-managed (native C/C++ ) functions ? I feel copying bitmap data from managed to unmanaged memory is not the fastest way and there should be a better alternative...

I found out few approaches, if someone could approve or suggest better alternatives:

Approach 1: **Using pin_ptr**
*'pin' the memory, use pin_ptr instead of copying (Marshalling) pixel data of Bitmap object from managed to unmanaged for increasing performance / speed*

Approach 2: **Unmanaged WPF Imaging Component**.

Approach 3: **HBitmap::LockBits()**
*It does lock the bitmap and makes available the pixel data handle, but I have seen it does allocate memory.*